# Having trouble with bar graph colors based on weekend in Coldfusion cfchart

Tags: coldfusion

I need to create graphs with daily data and we need the weekend bars to be a different color.  I am able to color my bar graph with the weekends being green via the Plot attribute and rules as shown in my code by using the #Dayofweek# function and it works great.  However, when I do this the X-axis labels are values of 1 through 7 as shown in in the first image below which won't work.  If I just use the date variable then it displays the X-axis labels correctly as shown in the 2nd attached image but will not correctly color the weekends a different color.

```
<cfscript>
   plot={"rules":[           
         {
         "rule":"'%k' == '1'",
         "background-color":"green" 
         },                            
         {
         "rule":"'%k' == '7'",   
         "background-color":"green" 
         }
   ]};
</cfscript>
<cfchartseries type="bar" query="mychartdata" itemcolumn="time" valuecolumn="interval">
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CADAhxn8n1bNjdx_vJpXA-UXIrOU-vXS

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cgUgtqSNPTHmC-_aaZoPnbO2CpCz_Qlt

Comment: Could you post a [small, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem? That has two benefits: 1) isolating the code will help you in troubleshooting the issue and 2) while people on S.O. enjoy helping, like you, they have busy schedules. Not everyone has time to write all the set up code required to reproduce the issue. So posting a runnable, copy and paste example will greatly increase your chance of getting a speedy answer :-)

Comment: In all honesty, you will be better off NOT using <cfchart> and it's child tags and, instead, using a charting library directly because it will be easier to use and style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Scott.  Are there any charting libraries you would suggest with Coldfusion?

Comment: Ageax, this isn't really a coding error issue.  The code is working, I just need assistance with formatting the graphs and I was wondering if anyone had ever been able to color bar graphs based on the day of the week using cfchart.

Comment: @user1636639 - That may be true, but not posting a working also limits your chances of getting an answer. Yes, the ideal is to find someone that's had the exact same issue, but that doesn't always happen. Often a second set of eyes can catch something you missed, just by working with the code. That's happened to me many times. However, if it takes too much time to set up the code, many won't bother. So it's a missed opportunity for free help :-)

Comment: That said, I agree with Scott about avoiding cfchart. It's really just zingcharts behinds the scenes, so you might start there. It's easier to use without the CF layer in the middle, limiting what you can and can't do with styling.